# how to play HLS link to specific external player apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, http-live-streaming

I want to play HLS from android sender to specific apk
I try this but it doesn't work

```
private void gotoUrl(String s) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://example.com/index.m3u8"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
startActivity(intent);
```

}

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. You can do it like this. I did it like this.

```
    private void playInMx(Context context, String videoTitle, String finalUrl) {

        String[] headers = {
                "HEADER_NAME", "HEADER_VALUE"// Separate it with comma (,) if you want to add more headers..
        };

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad", "com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad.ActivityScreen");
        intent.putExtra("package", context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("title", videoTitle);
        // Uncomment this if you want to setup headers
        //intent.putExtra("headers", headers);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(finalUrl), "video/*");
        intent.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: private void gotoUrl(String s) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://example.com/index.m3u8"));
intent.setClassName("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad","com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad.ActivityScreen");
intent.putExtra("package", getPackageName());
intent.putExtra("title", videoTitle);
        // Uncomment this if you want to setup headers
        //intent.putExtra("headers", headers);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(finalUrl), "video/*");
        intent.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: same problem it doesn't work

Comment: @achraf what's your **targetSdk** ? And also mention your **error log** also!

Comment: @achraf and also why did you add this action param? **Intent.ACTION_VIEW**?

Comment: targetSdk:30
And this is the error
https://i.ibb.co/v3186Qm/Screenshot-20220819-103604.png

Comment: @achraf I meant error log? from the android studio. Not a crash dialog.

Comment: No crash dialog

Comment: @achraf What!?. See [Official Doc](https://mx.j2inter.com/api)